# Split a matrix in N chunks

Tags: python, numpy

Given a matrix, I want to split it in  equally smaller matrices of `m` x `n` size. If the matrix is not divisible by the given size, we just put the remainder into a different matrix.

For example, given the matrix below and `m=2` and `n=2`:

```
[[1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1]]
```

Result:

```
[[1, 0],
 [0, 0]],

[[1],
 [0]],

[[0, 1]],

[[1]],
```

I was using `np.reshape` but it fails to split when the numbers don't match, as in the example above.

```
    matrix_size = matrix.shape[0] * matrix.shape[1]
    n_matrix = math.ceil(matrix_size / (m * n))
    matrix.reshape(n_matrix, m, n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is using multiple calls to [`numpy.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split)

```py
import numpy as np

matrix = [
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
]
sub_matrices = np.array_split(matrix, 2, axis=0)
sub_matrices = [m for sub_matrix in sub_matrices for m in np.array_split(sub_matrix, 2, axis=1)]
```

Where the first call to `array_split` splits it vertically, and the second call splits it horizontally.